# Jboss As 7.1 ModuleNotFoundException: Module com.oracle:main is not found

Tags: spring-mvc, oracle11g, jboss7.x

I'm deploying war file to JBoss As 7.1 , the same war file running properly with tomcat but with jboss it's giving flowing exception.

```
16:20:50,906 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.module.service."deployment.VSCAS.war".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service."deployment.VSCAS.war".main: Failed to load module: deployment.VSCAS.war:main
at  org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:91) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
 Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: Module com.oracle:main is not   found in local module loader @40dd550c (roots: E:\server\jboss-as-7.1.1.vsc\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules)
at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleLoader.findModule(LocalModuleLoader.java:126)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModuleLocal(ModuleLoader.java:275)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.preloadModule(ModuleLoader.java:222)
at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleLoader.preloadModule(LocalModuleLoader.java:94)
at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:841)
at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1181)
at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1207)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:208)
at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:70) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
... 5 more
```

I have given jboss-deployment-structure.xml file also with flowing content to avoid the error.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
<deployment>
<exclusions>
   <module name="org.hibernate"/>
    <module name="com.oracle" />
</exclusions>
 </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Can any please help me.

Answer (score 4):

By following the brief answer, I have done following steps:

1- Created directory structure 
                **oracle\ojdbc6\main** 
                     under
EAP-6.4.0\modules\system\layers\base\com\

2- Download and copy **ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar** and place it under **main** directory

3- Create **module.xml** file inside **main** directory with the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.oracle.ojdbc6">
    <properties>
        <property name="jboss.api" value="private"/>
    </properties>

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar"/>
        <!-- Insert resources here -->
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Comment: For JBoss EAP 7.2 on a mac, the path was slightly different. Better to Use the add command from the jboss Cli as described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54450930

Answer (score 3):

This error means your installation is missing the module com.oracle. This module is not included by default.
To fix this you need to create the com.oracle module with the required JAR files and corresponding module.xml. Place it /modules/system/layers/base

Hope this helps you and others.